# Pooling vs Subsampling: Multiple Definitions?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, definitions

I have seen people using *pooling* and *subsampling* synonymously. I have also seen people use them as different processes. I am not sure though if I have correctly inferred what they mean, when they use the terms with distinct meanings.
I think these people mean that the pooling part is selecting a submatrix from an input matrix and the subsampling part is selecting yet another submatrix that satisfies some condition from the first submatrix.

So say we have a $100 \times 100$ image. We do $10 \times 10$ non-overlapping pooling with $5 \times 5$ max subsampling. That would mean we slide the $10 \times 10$ "pool" across the image in strides of 10 and at every step we select the $5 \times 5$ submatrix *inside* the pool that has the maximum sum. That $5 \times 5$ matrix is what comes out of the $10 \times 10$ pool at the current potion. So in the end we have a $50 \times 50$ image.

Can you confirm that this usage of the terms *pooling* and *subsampling* exists?

I inferred this definition, as I cannot make sense of how some people use the two terms otherwise. For example in [this video](https://youtu.be/cDdpwAIsuD8?list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH&t=120), or rather the people from the paper he is talking about (which I can't find because he only has the author name on his slide and no year).

Comment: I think this is asking the same question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354944/difference-between-pooling-and-subsampling

Comment: @Recessive I had read that one. It does not cover the case where people use the terms not as synonyms. It does not explain what a "$10 \times 10$ pool $5 \times 5$ subsampling" is  supposed to be.

Comment: From what I know, a maxpooling layer is a method for subsampling. So in that case, the terms are somewhat interchangable, but other types of pooling layers may also be a form of subsampling.

Comment: @Recessive The person from the video answered me now, and he says in this case by _subsampling_ the authors meant the stride of the pooling.